# Using the foreach package for parallel processing over a function

Tags: r

I have a sparse matrix and I am tyring to calculate the cosine similarity between columns. The data set is approx 5,000 rows by 50,000 columns. The rows are words and the columns are some scores assigned to each word.

I apply the following code:

```
i1 <- seq_len(ncol(mat))
t1 <- Sys.time()
cosine_dist_mat <- sapply(i1, function(i) sapply(i1, function(j) cosine(mat[, i], mat[, j])))
t2 <- Sys.time()
t2 - t1
```

For a matrix of `10x10`, `100x100` and `1000x1000`. With the following times (in minutes)

```
plot(c(0.04010415, 3.540563, 12.94297))
```

So for the `10x10` the time takes less than a minute but for the `1000x1000` the time takes almost 13 minutes. So the increase appears exponential.

```
> head(mat)
6 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 10 column names ‘20_2005’, ‘1750_2005’, ‘2034_2005’ ... ]]

“account      . . . . . . . . . .
“amend        . . . . . . . . . .
“anticipate”  . . . . . . . . . .
“anticipates” . . . . . . . . . .
“asc          . . . . . . . . . .
“asc”         . . . . . . . . . .
```

I have been running the code for 2 days on a single CPU (I didn`t calculate previously the time it would take to compute the function).

Now I understand a little better I am looking into the `foreach` package to run the process parallel.

Does anyone know how its possible to incorporate parallel processing of the `sapply` function I have?

Data:

```
mat <- new("dgCMatrix", i = c(47L, 53L, 55L, 69L, 71L, 76L, 84L, 87L, 
90L, 97L, 47L, 49L, 50L, 52L, 56L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 69L, 71L, 76L, 
79L, 81L, 84L, 87L, 96L, 97L, 99L, 50L, 61L, 62L, 67L, 69L, 71L, 
76L, 77L, 81L, 84L, 87L, 96L, 99L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 55L, 59L, 61L, 
62L, 63L, 66L, 68L, 69L, 71L, 76L, 81L, 84L, 87L, 97L, 99L, 47L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 53L, 56L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 69L, 71L, 77L, 78L, 81L, 
96L, 97L, 99L, 49L, 56L, 61L, 62L, 69L, 71L, 75L, 78L, 81L, 84L, 
87L, 99L, 46L, 49L, 62L, 63L, 66L, 67L, 69L, 71L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 
81L, 84L, 87L, 96L, 97L, 99L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 53L, 61L, 62L, 69L, 
71L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 84L, 87L, 96L, 97L, 99L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 56L, 57L, 62L, 63L, 66L, 67L, 69L, 71L, 77L, 79L, 81L, 84L, 
87L, 96L, 97L, 99L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 55L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 68L, 
69L, 71L, 76L, 79L, 81L, 84L, 87L, 90L, 96L, 97L, 99L), p = c(0L, 
10L, 28L, 41L, 59L, 76L, 88L, 105L, 122L, 142L, 162L), Dim = c(100L, 
10L), Dimnames = list(Terms = c("“account", "“amend", "“anticipate”", 
"“anticipates”", "“asc", "“asc”", "“asu", "“asu”", 
"“believe”", "“believes”", "“busi", "“business”", 
"“cautionari", "“company”", "“continue”", "“credit", 
"“critic", "“disclosur", "“estimate”", "“estimates”", 
"“expect”", "“expects”", "“fair", "“fasb”", "“forwardlook", 
"“gaap”", "“incom", "“intend”", "“intends”", "“liquid", 
"“note", "“plan”", "“plans”", "“potential”", "“project”", 
"“result", "“risk", "“sec”", "“secur", "“select", 
"“sfas", "“special", "“summari", "“well", "“will”", 
"•chang", "aaa", "abandon", "abat", "abil", "abl", "abnorm", 
"abroad", "absenc", "absent", "absolut", "absorb", "absorpt", 
"abstract", "abus", "academ", "acceler", "accept", "access", 
"accessori", "accid", "accommod", "accompani", "accomplish", 
"accord", "accordion", "account", "accounting", "accounts", "accredit", 
"accret", "accru", "accrual", "accumul", "accur", "accuraci", 
"achiev", "acid", "acknowledg", "acquir", "acquire", "acquired", 
"acquisit", "acquisition", "acquisitiond", "acquisitionrel", 
"acquisitions", "acquisitionsu", "acquisitionu", "acr", "acreag", 
"across", "act", "act”", "action"), Docs = c("20_2005", "1750_2005", 
"2034_2005", "2062_2005", "2488_2005", "2969_2005", "3133_2005", 
"3327_2005", "3333_2005", "3453_2005")), x = c(0.00113980515407692, 
0.00682355899898636, 0.00347759367109875, 5.20001257200727e-05, 
2.47397153291907e-05, 0.000108319778164461, 0.000396999848727827, 
0.000603493824599814, 0.00398763664820086, 0.000273465937531601, 
0.000419330111519823, 0.000528449298979236, 0.000920819686932983, 
0.000666064278916234, 0.000390540724451623, 0.000336326269937498, 
0.000140334159251127, 0.000600340625202571, 0.000133914580991972, 
1.90307227407633e-05, 3.98504468022793e-05, 0.00116492829619315, 
0.00092504605067629, 0.000876328679046271, 0.000602634269230779, 
0.000416814888082897, 0.000503035548101499, 0.00126018557913386, 
0.000156338718399063, 0.000742328431697948, 4.4248714784307e-05, 
0.000355437905498253, 0.000126673679410513, 1.18706939075604e-05, 
8.79566133287654e-05, 0.000313662207759417, 0.000157056279394439, 
0.000161183685832125, 0.000280024170106673, 0.000459990149203084, 
0.000309048969614686, 0.00504421844906945, 0.000381235929496257, 
0.000547501060433858, 0.00384577193682792, 0.00114672352310616, 
0.000649911947127846, 0.000335746257334945, 0.000193348235300333, 
0.000611910514753471, 0.000569469982715089, 7.39355915972189e-05, 
6.92856464586234e-06, 5.13376122933583e-05, 9.16689953676532e-05, 
0.001223014488113, 0.00114409141206702, 0.000388823403657316, 
0.000360765054071308, 0.000626141368137108, 0.000220941707332476, 
0.0006345982091375, 0.000864881880996905, 0.000535494102642698, 
0.00116630643401737, 0.00100440099584482, 8.98055051439052e-05, 
0.000448212625430376, 0.000142828928897222, 2.53278109170883e-05, 
0.000424397908499662, 0.000822198587001557, 0.00031875543901768, 
0.000622385650623143, 0.000901355827278763, 0.00188170203128431, 
7.06152424069764e-05, 0.00130467236782308, 0.000374519705191304, 
6.69731142246855e-05, 0.000106515721439292, 1.98097861862727e-05, 
0.00765000679742822, 0.000613160627451439, 0.000316952275815201, 
0.000243961286898647, 0.000423833569441392, 0.000155921454773087, 
0.000439822416240934, 0.000362718010375718, 2.75208058908751e-05, 
0.000618094368395823, 0.000326025252263801, 0.000110533578784822, 
2.62618681659884e-05, 2.1297298021434e-05, 2.73526236190051e-05, 
0.000292626693581789, 9.44857208935703e-05, 0.000537252543972119, 
0.000225561039284774, 0.000957896738312893, 0.000143047088143026, 
0.000483384262049943, 0.00124939896768756, 0.000240145147451988, 
0.000241414302537583, 0.0006580379618847, 0.000407426095570545, 
0.000382094941946792, 2.27759161373593e-05, 4.34680662572646e-05, 
7.0501638013349e-06, 0.0003716542830774, 4.52734606794179e-05, 
0.000161449754511765, 0.00015639068592562, 0.000414826298245946, 
0.000504473964058679, 0.000710305176997578, 0.0012572795603698, 
0.000318150411761914, 0.00105877105901901, 0.000228630388793112, 
0.000574596722388701, 0.000783106991035519, 0.000528015872592884, 
0.00316437784917878, 0.000162628725278892, 0.000202916981010363, 
0.000642193781129678, 0.000217725395222404, 5.17297611149423e-05, 
1.78989716073174e-05, 0.000192135467529887, 0.000787498706679388, 
0.000577233997404633, 0.000493669655913719, 0.000514590921495855, 
0.00112707773126517, 0.00108817641693684, 0.000567928811290766, 
0.000525119733117927, 0.00145626197138337, 0.000496177965403544, 
0.000570575561526461, 0.000365325543047343, 0.000144054828039969, 
0.000120215487079327, 0.00102854844547273, 0.000378673914811766, 
9.83282025878094e-05, 1.38216242020314e-05, 0.000102412147510543, 
0.000498960564151545, 0.000487648633239346, 0.000187673976805267, 
0.0002445342839795, 0.000418906192545259, 0.000178529607688508, 
0.000775654300853724, 0.000959575180423929), factors = list())
```

Edit:

I have set up an AWS t2.large instance with 4 CPUs. (I can always add more CPUs later).

Comment: How sparse is the sparse matrix? If sparse then there are shortcuts to computing the dot product for sparse vectors. But to be clear you really want to calculate (50000 choose 2) values?

Comment: How is `cosine` implemented?

Comment: The cosine is applied using the package `lsa`. The sparse matrix is very sparse. What shortcuts do you know for computing the dot product of sparse matrices?

Comment: Intuitively if the matrix is very sparse, to compute the dot product between two vectors, we encode each vector by its non-zero elements and compare those. But you shouldn't need to implement this yourself, ex. https://rdrr.io/cran/qlcMatrix/man/cosSparse.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I have looked at the `cosSparse()` function before and for some reason I moved on from it but cannot remember why! I am now applying it on the sparse matrix for a small sample and for the `1000x1000` matrix which originally took 12-13 minutes this was instant. I am now applying it on the full dataset and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay now I realise why I did not continue with this method - I get this error: `Error in .local(x, y, ...) : 
  Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 147`